# Как реализовать на iPad интерфейс похожий на программу Finder в Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, swift

Условно: есть папки, есть конечные элементы, у конечных элементов есть детали. Все как в Finder на mac. Как реализовать подобный интерфейс на iPad?

Возможно есть какие-то готовые решения, но я их сходу не нашел. Вижу варианты:

1. Сделать кастомный контроллер-контейнер. Который бы содержал контейнеры 2х типов, условно: `TableViewController` и `DetailViewController`
2. Делать все в одном контроллере, содержащем `Scroll View`, в котором программно отрисовывать `TableView` и `DetailView`.

Буду благодарен за любую информацию и помощь.

Comment: UISplitViewController подходит для этого. Если в ландскейпе, то слева в главной таблице можно расположить дерево папок. Справа - details.

Comment: Это будет не совсем похоже на Finder.

Answer (score 0):

Извиняюсь. Не смог отредактировать вопрос, поэтому пишу уточнение вопроса в его ответе.

Окно Finder в необходимом режиме:
[image: Finder в необходимом режиме]

Необходимо сделать без левой, верхней и нижней панелей. Вот так:
[image: Необходимо сделать так].

Comment: Как бы хозяин-барин. Но по-хорошему тут должен быть UINavigationController и на каждый уровень - свой UITableViewController. Соответсвенно вся навигация и все такое соответствует стандартному положению вещей в айос.